# Java Junit testing problem

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testcase

I am using Junit 4. My whole program is working fine. I am trying to write a test case. But there is one error...

here is very basic sample test

```
public class di  extends TestCase{
    private static Records testRec;
    public void testAbc() {
        Assert.assertTrue(
            "There should be some thing.",
            di.testRec.getEmployee() > 0);
    }

}
```

and when i run this it give me error that

```
fName can not be null
```

if i use super and do like this

```
public TestA() {
super("testAbc");
}
```

it work all fine. It wasn't this before with JUnit 3.X 
am I doing wrong or they changed it :(
Sorry if I am not clear

Is there any way to executre test without super? or calling functions etc. ?

Comment: what is TestAgnes? It isn't mentioned in the first code snippet. Please clear your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In JUnit 4 you need not extend `TestCase`, instead use the `@Test` annotation to mark your test methods:

```
public class MyTest {
    private static Records testRec;
    @Test
    public void testAbc() {
        Assert.assertTrue(
            "There should be some thing.",
            MyTest.testRec.getEmployee() > 0);
    }
}
```

As a side note, testing a `static` member in your class may make your unit tests dependent on each other, which is not a good thing. Unless you have a very good reason for this, I would recommend removing the `static` qualifier.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I tried this, it gave me error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test to Annotation" what should I to avoid this error? It gives me if I used @Test

Comment: Sounds like you imported some other Test class which is not an annotation. Make sure you import `org.junit.Test`, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: I want to make an additional note, if you are getting the "Type mismatch" error above, you might be doing what I did and named your test class "Test" which conflicts with the import.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your case but this error may also mean that you have a file named `Test.java` in your project. Renaming it will fix the error but after refactoring `@Test` will be changed to `@NewName` (at least in Eclipse) so remember to manually change it back to `@Test`.